# Stack overflow error producing JSON with Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to convert Java Objects into JSON and display it on a web page. What is happening is that the Plugs get printed once and the Details and Users are being printed infinitely.

Here is how I'm trying to print it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json/{userName}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody()
public List<Plugs> getPlugs(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
    User userInfo = userDAO.getUserInfo(userName);
    System.out.println("------Here's the thing------");
    System.out.println(userInfo.getDetails().getPlugs());
    return userInfo.getDetails().getPlugs();
}
```

Here are the relationships between each table using JPA

```
//User.java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Details details;
```

--

```
//Details.java
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
private User user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "details", targetEntity = Plugs.class)
private List<Plugs> plugs;
```

--

```
//Plugs.java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_code", referencedColumnName = "post_code")
private Details details;
```

I've already tried methods such as `@JsonIgnore` on both the private fields and getters or `@JsonBackReference`and `@JsonManagedReference` (but maybe someone could tell me how to do that one again) and `@JsonIdentityInfo` (again maybe someone could help me with that one as well).

**Question:** How do print JUST the plugs and nothing else in JSON format?

If more code is needed, I'll provide more.

Comment: Share your exact stacktrace.

Comment: and what has JPA got to do with your JSON generation (i.e the problem) ?

Comment: @NeilStockton Nothing. I'm just saying I'm using JPA.

Comment: @NeilStockton Oh I didn't even realized JPA was tagged. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Here is where I changed the code

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "username")
@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
private User user
```

--

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_code", referencedColumnName = "post_code")
@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
private Details details;
```

And at the top of each entity, I put this

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
```